# How do I refactor a code with a lot of for loops?

Tags: apex

I am trying to update a field on a list of Opportunities when a new Docusign status (DS) is created. This is like a maze to get from DS object to Opportunity. The DS object has a field for the envelope id. From the envelope id you can get to the envelope object which has a field called "List of Opportunities." This is a text area field and has a list of opportunity Ids listed like this "OppId1,OppId2,OppId3" etc. So basically a list if ids in text format. From those opportunity id values you can update the field "Status Docusign" in the opportunity record with the DS Id. I wrote the code for it, but it is to be honest very bad and seems inefficient. Is there any way to refactor this code so there aren't so many `for` loops?

Here is the apex:

```
public class DocusignStatusClass {
    
    public static void onAfterInsert( List<DocuSign_Status__c> docusign_status ) {
        List<Opportunity> accOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
        List<String> OppsSplit;
        for(DocuSign_Status__c ds : docusign_status){
            List<Envelope__c> OppsInEnv = [SELECT List_Opportunities__c FROM Envelope__c where dfsle__DocuSignId__c =: ds.dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c];
            
            for(Envelope__c opps : OppsInEnv){
               OppsSplit = opps.List_Opportunities__c.split(',');  
                for(String o : OppsSplit){
                    List<Opportunity> finalOpp = [SELECT Id, Recent_DS_Agreement__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: o];
                    for(Opportunity fo : finalOpp){
                        fo.Recent_DS_Agreement__c = ds.Id;
                        accOpps.add(fo);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            update accOpps;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a map or two. Without being able to compile this, I came up with:

```
public static void onAfterInsert(DocuSign_Status__c[] docusign_status) {
    Set<Id> envelopeIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Set<Id>> oppsByStatus = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
    for(DocuSign_Status__c record: docusign_status) {
        envelopeIds.add(record.dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c);
        oppsByStatus.put(record.Id, new Set<Id>());
    }
    Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<id>();
    for(Envelope__c record: [select dfsle__DocuSignId__c, List_Opportunities__c from Envelope__c where dfsle__DocuSignId__c = :envelopeIds]) {
        Set<Id> oppIdsForEnvelope = new Set<Id>(record.List_Opportunities__c.split(','));
        opportunityIds.addAll(oppIdsForEnvelope);
        oppsByStatus.get(record.dfsle__DocuSignId__c).addAll(oppIdsForEnvelope);
    }
    Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opportunityIds FOR UPDATE]);
    for(Id docusignStatusId: oppsByStatus.keySet()) {
        for(Id oppId: oppsByStatus.get(docusignStatusId)) {
            Opportunity thisOpp = opps.get(oppId);
            if(thisOpp != null) {
                thisOpp.Recent_DS_Agreement__c = docusignStatusId;
            }
        }
    }
    update opps.values();
}
```

Which should be a close approximation of what you need.

Comment: Hello sfdcfox, thank you for your help. I was curious, this still has 4 for loops. So isnt your code adding more compelxity than what I had? I thought maps would eliminate/reduce the for loops?

Comment: @user3688231 The goal of using Maps is to reduce the number of queries. In this case, we use a constant two queries, instead of 1 + 1 query per envelope + 1 query per opportunity, which will quickly hit limits. This also avoids the deeply nested loops. You could save one more loop, actually. I'll revise.

Comment: @user3688231 Actually, no, this is likely the optimal solution. If we take out the second for loop in the last loop, then we need another for loop in the middle for loop. Four is the minimal number of loops we can use here.

Comment: I am getting an error on line Set<Ids>oppIdsForEnvelope line. It says Invalid Initializer type List found for Set: exepected a List or set of type Id

Comment: I replaced that line with this: Set<String> oppIdsForEnvelopeString = new Set<String>(record.Related_Opportunities__c.split(','));
            Set<Id> oppIdsForEnvelope = new Set<Id>((List<Id>)new List<String>( oppIdsForEnvelopeString )); Do you agree? Thanks again

Comment: @user3688231 Yes, that looks fine.

Comment: another question I had was that you are setting the field value on the thisOpp variable. However we update the opps.values(). Shouldnt we be updating thisOpp.values()?

Comment: @user3688231 `thisOpp` refers to just one of the opportunities in the map. When we do this, we're updating by *reference*. The value in `thisOpp` is also in `opps` (and also `opps.values()`). This allows us to use only one DML statement for performance reasons.